# accessing a Fragment from a static method

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi i'm trying to detect if my fragment isAdded i have used `this.isAdded()` however in a static method i can't use this. So is there a way to access a fragment from a static method?

Comment: Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

```
this
```

returns reference to object

```
static
```

tells that some field or method are general for it's class, not just an object. So you can't use "static" with "this".

You can try passing your fragment into your static method like this

```
class SomeFrag extends Fragment
  {
     public static bool yourMethod(SomeFrag fragmentYouwantToCheck)
                  {
                     return fragmentYouwantToCheck.isAdded();
                  }
  }
```

i hope, i've got you right)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it first i created a `public Fragment frag`

then in my onCreateView i `frag = this;` then i can call frag from static methods